# Difference between @html.Label and @html.LabelFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

What is the difference between `@html.Label()` and `@html.LabelFor()`?

Also, what is the syntax to use these methods in case of Strongly Typed and non-strongly typed views in context of Razor?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`LabelFor` will use the `Model` you have setted on your View to create a typed html helper. It make the life easy to your code, and generate the HTML based on your model, since you use the `Attributes` such as `Display()` on the properties of your Model.

```
// Model
public class YourModel
{
    [DisplayName("Some property")]
    public string YourProperty { get; set; }
}
```

and in the View...

```
// View
@model YourModel
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.YourProperty)
```

`Label` is just used to generated a Label in your View, it is not necessary to be related by `Model`.

```
// View
@Html.Label("YourProperty")
```

Both will generate this HTML Output

```
<label for="YourProperty">YourProperty</label>
```

Both will generate a `label` tag.

If your View or PartialView is not typed with a Model, you cannot use `LabelFor`, `EditorFor`, `TextBoxFor` html helpers, just the `Label`, `TextBox` etc..

If you add a `Html.Label("field")` in a non-typed Partial View, it will generate using the Model of the main View. Everytime you cann a partial view from a View, the model is passed. If the model is null, it just render a `label` tag, if the model has this property, the html helper will read the value and render it.

Look at the [internal code source of asp.net mvc for Label extensions](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/LabelExtensions.cs).

Comment: Thanks! that is helpful.. What if the view is Non-Strongly typed view? What would be the syntax of Label and LabelFor??

Comment: I add some comments on my anwser. Take a look!

Comment: @FelipeOriani Span tag/element?

Comment: Just one more question.. How we use Label for non-strongly typed view?
when we give @html.Label("xyz"), how razor knows which Model's property is xyz??

Comment: I add some edits, look!

Comment: Thanks for all your answers!

Comment: @Felipe .. You says that 
"Both will generate this HTML Output
<label for="YourProperty">YourProperty</label>"

But I think @Html.LabelFor(m => m.YourProperty) will generate a different output as
<label for="YourProperty">Some property</label>.

Let me know If I am wrong.

Comment: @himanshupareek66 Yes, you are right friend, the LabelFor generate specifique for the property, and also read some attributes that property can have :)